# Circular progress bar with arrow

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been trying to create a **circular progress bar** that has an **arrow at the front**.

**This is what I have so far**

**HTML**

```
<!--  Container  -->
<ul class="progress">
    <!--  Item  -->
    <li data-name="Item 1" data-percent="Item 1">
        <svg viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
        <g fill="none" stroke-width="2" transform="translate(100,100)">
        <path d="M 0,-100 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,-50" stroke="url(#cl1)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 86.6,50" stroke="url(#cl2)"/>
        <path d="M 86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,100" stroke="url(#cl3)"/>
        <path d="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,50" stroke="url(#cl4)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,50 A 100,100 0 0,1 -86.6,-50" stroke="url(#cl5)"/>
        <path d="M -86.6,-50 A 100,100 0 0,1 0,-100" stroke="url(#cl6)"/>
        </g>
        </svg>
        <svg viewBox="-10 -10 220 220">
        <path d="M200,100 C200,44.771525 155.228475,0 100,0 C44.771525,0 0,44.771525 0,100 C0,155.228475 44.771525,200 100,200 C155.228475" stroke-dashoffset="590"></path>
        </svg>
    </li>
</ul>
<!--  Defining Angle Gradient Colors  -->
<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
<linearGradient id="cl1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
    <stop stop-color="#18FFA9"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#18FFA9"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl2" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop stop-color="#18FFA9"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4FC0EB"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl3" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1">
    <stop stop-color="#4FC0EB"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FD8AE6"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl4" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="1" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
    <stop stop-color="#FD8AE6"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4FC0EB"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl5" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="0" y2="0">
    <stop stop-color="#4FC0EB"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#18FFA9"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="cl6" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
    <stop stop-color="#18FFA9"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#18FFA9"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.progress {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.progress > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 34px;
}
.progress > li:after {
    content: attr(data-percent);
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 20%;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 193px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.progress svg {
  width: 409px;
  height: 409px;
}
.progress svg:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.progress svg:nth-child(2) path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 25;
  stroke-dasharray: 629;
  stroke: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  animation: load 1s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qr7cs40t/1

The code is not made by me, I took it from an example that I found around and made some styling modifications.

Working with SVG has become a challenge since I don't have experience with it. I tried looking at multiple tutorials on how to add the arrow using svg but did not succeed.

I'm currently facing **two challenges**:

- Add an arrow at the front of the progress wheel, so the arrow moves along the progress.
- Change the direction. Currently it goes clockwise, I need it to go also **counterclockwise**. So I will have 3 of these, two clockwise, one counterclockwise on my page.

The arrow needs to be something like this https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-from-bottom?style=light so it's the same width as the circular progress bar.

Here's an example of how it should look
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it. I took some base code that I found and modified it to get the result that I needed.

Direct link
https://codepen.io/lucky8919/pen/JjWXBYX

**HTML**

```
  <div class="progress multicolor">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <span class="progress-left">
      <span class="progress-bar"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="progress-right">
      <span class="progress-bar"></span>
    </span>
    <div class="progress-value">90%</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
}


* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.progress {
  width: 390px;
  height: 390px;
  line-height: 390px;
  background: none;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: relative;
}

.progress:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 12px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.progress > span:not(.arrow) {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.progress > span.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    animation: rotate 2.7s linear forwards;
}

.progress > span.arrow:after {
    content: "";
    border-width: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 198px;
    top: -5px;
}

.progress .progress-left {
  left: 1px;
}

.progress .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.progress .progress-left .progress-bar {
  left: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 320px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 320px;
  border-left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.progress .progress-right {
  right: 1px;
}

.progress .progress-right .progress-bar {
  left: -100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 320px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 320px;
  border-right: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
  transform-origin: center right;
  animation: loading-1 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress .progress-value {
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 390px;
    width: 98%;
    height: 98%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.progress.multicolor .progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px transparent;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}

.progress.multicolor .progress-left .progress-bar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(95.14deg, red 75%, blue 85%, green 100%);
}

.progress.multicolor .progress-right .progress-bar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(95.14deg, green 0%, blue 25%, red 50%);
}

.progress.multicolor .progress-left .progress-bar {
  animation: loading-2 1.2s linear forwards 1.5s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg)}
    to {transform:rotate(324deg)}
}

@keyframes loading-1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loading-2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
    transform: rotate(144deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get to the result you want by starting from this code sample.

At animation start, the visible colored arc is mostly hidden by a thick black stroked arc over-drawn on it. This arc has a stroke-dasharray that is then animated so that the unstroked part of the dasharray is progressively shifted along the curve to reveal the underlying colored arc. Because the reveal is created by the movement of a dasharray, there is no way to adjust the position of a marker (which is how you'd normally do this) so that it follows the reveal edge (at least using CSS).

You'll have to completely restructure the SVG and do the animation in JavaScript or SMIL.